# Can I find the connected components of a graph using matrix operations on the graph's adjacency matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, connectedness, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

If I have an adjacency matrix for a graph, can I do a series of matrix operations on the adjacency matrix to find the connected components of the graph?

Comment: Hint: square the matrix, cube the matrix etc... to power of matrix to number of nodes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes! Perhaps the easiest way is to obtain the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) matrix and find a basis of its kernel.

In words, call $A$ your adjacency matrix. Obtain the diagonal matrix $D$ of the degrees of each vertex. Set $L=D-A$. Now $\dim \ker L = $ number of connected components. Moreover, the kernel of $L$ is spanned by vectors constant on each connected component.

For example, a block diagonal matrix $A=diag(A_1,\dots,A_n)$, with blocks representing the connected components of your graph, will have an associated Laplacian matrix $L$ with kernel spanned by vectors $v_i=(0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1,0,\dots,0)$ where the string of ones is as long as the number of vertices in $A_i$, and specifically in the entries corresponding to the vertices of that connected component.

EDIT: Edited to more directly answer the original question. Sorry that I misread it earlier!

Comment: In what text would someone find a result such as this?

Comment: @PaulSundheim By googling "spectral graph theory book" I found this book by Fan Chung http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/cbms.pdf

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't quite answer my question. I would like to find the actual connected components, not just how many there are. Thank you, though!

Comment: @user2073068 I think slightly better can be done. My memory is failing me, so I can't remember specifics (which is why I didn't explain above), but I think you can find the connected components easily from the Laplacian. Maybe by checking the eigenbasis corresponding to the eigenvalue 0? If I have time to check I will augment my answer.

Comment: @user2073068 I have edited my answer to more directly answer your problem. I apologize for reading your question too quickly earlier!

Comment: Wow, this is super cool! Thank you so much. To complete the task I was looking at, I ended up just using SciPy's connected_component function, but its interesting to know this anyway.

Comment: What's the time complexity compared with BFS or DFS?

Comment: Well, I guess if you use Gaussian elimination your algorithm is $O(n^3)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices. I'm not sure how that compares.

Comment: Why -1 in dim ker L = number of connected components - 1?

Comment: @kentzo that was a mistake, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to replace dim with the rank operator?

Comment: Chung's book assumes normalized Laplacian. See http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/2009/index.html for more general theory.

Answer (score 4):

If you want use the adjacency matrix and you need the actual components, not just their number, then a brute force approach is as follows. Suppose the graph has adjacency matrix $A$ and $n$ vertices. Compute $M=(A+I)^n$. Now define vertices $u$ and $v$ to be equivalent if $M_{u,v} \ne 0$. The equivalence classes of this relation are the connected components of the graph.

This works because $M_{u,v}$ is positive if and only if there is a walk of length at most $n-1$ from from $u$ to $v$, and if two vertices are in the same component they are joined by a walk of length at most $n$.

It is not practical because no-one in their right mind would compute such a large power of $A$. It could be made workable, but there are other methods for finding components, e.g., find a spanning forest.

Comment: Hate to necro an old thread, but I think the high power of $M$ is pretty easily computable in $O(n^3 \log n)$ time. Just perform repeated squaring of $M$ for $\lceil \log_2 n\rceil$ iterations.

Comment: I did say it could be made workable.

Answer (score 3):

If the graph is regular, the multiplicity of the largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix will provide the same result. Let $X_{1}, ..., X_{n}$ be the connected components of the graph. Then these are the diagonal submatrices of the adjacency matrix. And so $p_{G}(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} p_{X_{i}}(\lambda)$, where $p_{G}(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\lambda$.

Since $G$ is $k$-regular, $\lambda = k$ is the dominant eigenvalue of each component as well as of $G$. And so $k$ appears $n$ times.

If $G$ is not regular, then you should use the Laplacian method as described above.